# Cannot Start MySql after copying data folder between 2 same installations in Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb

I had a Xampp installation in my PC which I was using for some development purpose and due to some circumstances the data folder in mysql was copied and with new windows installation same xampp was reinstalled and data folder was copied back, but after this my mysql is not starting at all and giving the below error, can anyone help me out as to how can i fix it? I have searched various recovery modes of InnoDB and nothing seems to be working, In Newer versions of Xampp I can see DB in phpMyAdmin but no tables , I the exact same version which I was using, I am getting this error

```
2021-05-09  0:09:54 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: Aria engine: starting recovery
recovered pages: 0% 11% 21% 31%210509  0:09:55 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.4.17-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=33554432
read_buffer_size=8388608
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=65537
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 76866 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
VCRUNTIME140.dll!memcmp()
mysqld.exe!strmov()
mysqld.exe!strmov()
mysqld.exe!strmov()
mysqld.exe!strmov()
mysqld.exe!strmov()
mysqld.exe!strmov()
mysqld.exe!strmov()
mysqld.exe!?ha_initialize_handlerton@@YAHPEAUst_plugin_int@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPEAHPEAPEADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPEAHPEAPEADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?init_net_server_extension@@YAXPEAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?win_main@@YAHHPEAPEAD@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_service@@YAXPEAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysqld_main@@YAHHPEAPEAD@Z()
mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file at C:\xampp2\mysql\data\
Minidump written to C:\xampp2\mysql\data\mysqld.dmp
```

Edit: The error was fixed by removing aria_control_log file but I still cannot see the tables in the database, the database folder in data has ibd files and I also have all the ibData1 and other files, The tables are not visible in phpMyAdmin

Comment: see the mysql error log it should tell you more about the problem

Comment: have posted the log, it crashes

Comment: an error log looks like `2020-06-17T18:46:22.478765Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server]and some text` which you haven't posted

Comment: i can see the error log in the question but the issue was solved but I still cant see the tables in phpmyadmin, any idea how can i recover?

Comment: in most cases you have more than one server, or the data was not recognized. As i said without the error log nobody can give you an answer

Comment: okay thanks, also i have ibdata1,iblog and database table's ibd files, Upon researching more it seems tables wont be visible since there is no frm file ? I never used file_per_table option in xampp